# Extjs add unique combobox value to store

Tags: extjs, combobox, store

I have combobox which is attached to a store. When i type something into combobox and press Enter i add combobox value to the store. The problem is that i want to only add values that are not in store. This is example code:

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name'],
    data : [
        {name:"Alabama"},
        {name:"Alaska"},
        {name:"Arizona"}        
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'name',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
                specialkey: function(field, e){                    
                    var store = this.getStore();
                    if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {                       
                        store.add({name: this.getValue()});
                    }
                }
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the value in the store before you add it:

```
specialkey: function(field, e){                    
    var store = this.getStore();

    if (e.getKey() !== e.ENTER) {  
        return;
    }  

    if(store.find('name', this.getValue(), null, null, true) === -1) {
        store.add({name: this.getValue()});
    }         
 }
```

a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1022) with the answer

Comment: It is not adding after first addition of record

Comment: Thank you my friend. But can u explain me how it works?

Comment: @MarkoNikolic I am not sure what you want me to explain. you can look and [find](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-find) doc at sencha site

Comment: Yes i found it, i understand. Thanks for help :)